# My AWS Connect Customer Profile isn't getting enabled on S3 | CCP doesn't show Customer Profile Board

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-connect

I am trying to enable AWS Connect Customer Profile on agent CCP using S3. I have followed a tutorial that is  [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/unify-and-organize-customer-information-with-amazon-connect-customer-profiles-with-the-pre-built-amazon-s3-connector/). I want to enable customer profile as you can see in the following agent dashboard:

[image: This is the picture of CCP having Customer Profiles enabled]

I have followed each step and made absolute configuration as mentioned in the tutorial but it didn't come up with the desired result. When I login into the agent desktop, there is no customer profile box present there, although I have made the accurate configuration.

[image: My CCP isn't showing any Customer Profile board here]

Answer (score 0):

you can check your connect instance from AWS console:
Amazon Connect > connectid > Customer Profiles > data mappings

you can check the created mappings.

And you can search the created profile with the customer id (which is mapped to account number),.